# In prototype is there a way of assessing what is listening to a dom objects events?

Tags: prototype

I've added an event listener to my prototype code, and I was wondering if there was a way to check what is observing a given dom element for events?

Preferably inspecting using firebug but javascript code will do.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, there is not. Not in prototype, and not in vanilla JavaScript.

The prototype API is available at http://prototypejs.org/api but having just taken another look to be sure, there does not appear to be any way to do that.

One option for you however, is make a registry of your own.

**Edit**

for example:

```
var EventRegistry = function() {
    var events=[];
    this.addEvent = function (element, func) {
        events.push({element:element,func:func});
        element.observe(func);
    }

    this.clearEvents = function(element) {
        events = events.reject(function(e) { 
            if (e.element == element) { 
                e.element.stopObserving(e.func); 
                return true;
            } else return false; 
        });
    }

    this.clearAllEvents = function (element) {
        events.each(function(e) { e.element.stopObserving(e.func); });
        events = [];
    }
}();
```

(Note: not tested.)

Comment: that's irritating... Does anyone know how prototype manages observers? Is there a variable that might list them?